# Contextual links for custom blocks: Add "Edit block content"

Tags: blocks, 8, navigation, entities

has somebody an idea, how to customize the contextual links in D8?

I have created a custom block type and it would be wonderful to have a link in the contextual links menu: "Edit block content".

Comment: Sounds like core should do that by default, I suggest you open a feature request.

Comment: Thanks - i agree (and would open a feature request), but one thing i do not understand so far: (https://www.drupal.org/node/2101565) If somebody creates a "Custom block" - do this automatically means, that there are fields and therefore they are editable for the user. Is the meaning here: "Custom block" means "Content block" in the sense of fieldable entity? If a developer f.e. generates a block via the Block API that prints out some stuff - "Edit block content" would make no sense here (?) ...

Comment: That naming there is very confusing. That is about defining your own block plugin in code. That is not an entity, or fieldable or anything. block_content.module (called custom blocks in 7.x and partially still in the UI because it was renamed), provides a content entity (Block content), that is then exposed as blocks that can be placed. If you want to create content with fields in the UI, use that, if you have different requirements, (e.g. blocks that load data from somewhere, and are dynamic), you create a block plugin, where you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I created the issue 2407761 on drupal.org: (https://www.drupal.org/node/2407761)

Answer (score 1):

The missing "edit" link was a bug in early Drupal 8 betas, and has been fixed as of beta5:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2284917